# Painting on a Component from within its LayoutManager

Tags: java, swing, drawing, awt, layout-manager

I'm developing an application and I have a panel that needs a custom LayoutManager. To test my LayoutManager implementation, I would like to have some debug mode built in, very much like MigLayout's debug mode, which draws dashed rectangles when debug mode is on.

In my custom LayoutManager, this is what I tried:

```
@Override
public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
    // compX.setBounds(...); // calculate for all components and set bounds

    parent.getGraphics().drawRect(0,0,parent.getWidth(), parent.getHeight());
}
```

It doesn't work as you probably expected.

I don't want to modify the panels that are being layed out - just like MigLayout, you specify `"debug"` in the MigLayout constructor and you have your dashed lines and you do not need to modify anything in the component that is being layed out.

How can I draw on `parent` while not modifying its internals?

Comment: parent.getGraphics() is designated for printing to File, BufferedImage and Printer

Comment: @mKorbel How do you mean? If I implement a panel for custom drawing, I use its Graphics object and use the methods provided to draw on it?

Comment: how about looking into mig's code ;-)

Comment: How do you mean? don't to use Xxx.getGraphics(), this is very volatille snapshot, that will be expired on 1st repaint(is implemented in API), you need to 1. create LayoutManager, 2. create painting as separate logics, 3. stop repainting by setIgnoreRepaint

Comment: @kleopatra DYM red lines around JComponent

Comment: @kleopatra I did, as far as I understand their implementation, they wrap components into others which they can fully control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the thingies to paint are hidden details of the LayoutManager, that is the manager itself is indeed the *only* collaborator with enough knowledge to *be able* to do the painting, you need a debug painting hook which has no other means but use `parent.getGraphics()` As such painting doesn't survive for long, using code must call it repeatedly, f.i. in a Timer.

A LayoutManager with a debug painting hook (note: it's just an example, no hidden state that would justify the trick :)

```
public static class MyBorderLayout extends BorderLayout {
    Color[] colors = new Color[] {Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.CYAN, Color.MAGENTA};
    public void paintDebug(Container parent) {
        Graphics g = parent.getGraphics();

        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getComponentCount(); i++) {
            Component child = parent.getComponents()[i];
            g.setColor(colors[i % colors.length]);
            Rectangle r = child.getBounds();
            g.drawRect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
        }
    }
}
```

// usage:

```
final JComponent comp = new JPanel(new MyBorderLayout());
comp.add(new JTable(10, 3));
comp.add(new JLabel("east"), BorderLayout.EAST);
comp.add(new JLabel("west"), BorderLayout.WEST);
comp.add(new JLabel("north"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
comp.add(new JLabel("south"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
ActionListener l = new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ((MyBorderLayout) comp.getLayout()).paintDebug(comp);
    }

};
showInFrame(comp, "debug");
new Timer(400, l).start();
```

Comment: Aha! The loop did the trick - I implemented a Thread in my custom LayoutManager that simply draws a rectangle every x ms (drawing on the EDT, of course) and now I see it. Probably the reason why you can specify a number (`"debug 33"`) in MigLayout's constraints, specifying the debug repaint interval! This approach will certainly do, as its debug only. Perfect!

Comment: @Timmos basically I just copied what Mig is doing (it's bit clouded there, because the layout workhorse is independent of the ui framework)